# Rails 4 - Passing Params via link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a single form - depending which link the user clicks to display the form, I want different hidden params to be passed to the record and saved upon submission.  Is there a nice way to do this?  Thanks in advance!

For instance:

```
<%= link_to 'General Request', new_request_path %>

<%= link_to 'Project Request', new_request_path %> ### -> set request.project = true

<%= link_to 'Administrative Request', new_request_path %>  ### -> set request.admin = true
```

Answer (score 9):

For your examples, you'd use:

```
<%= link_to 'Project Request', new_request_path(project: true) %>
```

which would produce a link like `http://127.0.0.1:3000/request?project=true`

and

```
<%= link_to 'Administrative Request', new_request_path(admin: true) %>
```

which would produce a link like `http://127.0.0.1:3000/request?admin=true`

Comment: hrm. Yeah, give it a shot. I based my answer on `new_request_path`, which looks like it goes to the `new` action. So my `link_to` examples would pass the `project` and `admin` parameters to the page with the form on it. That sounds a bit earlier than where it sounds like you want the parameters (in the form itself, being passed to the `create` action).

Comment: yeah, I want the params in the create action, like hidden field params, only dynamically based on what link was clicked to get there.(if that makes sense) - Thanks! I'll tinker with these ideas.

Comment: Just to add on a last bit which made this work for me, if you want to retrieve that parameter in a form, you could use something like `<%= f.hidden_field :admin, value: params[:admin] %>`.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two ways to accomplish what you are trying to do.

1. Create 3 different routes to accomplish different types of the requests. For example, `new_request_path`, `new_project_request_path`, `new_admin_request_path`.
2. If you are requesting new project, use `<%= link_to 'Project Request', new_request_path(:request_type => 'project') %>`. In the controller, you can handle different request types like this.

```rb
def new
  case params[:request_type]
  when 'general'
    do_something
  when 'project'
    do_something_1
  when 'admin'
    do_something_else
  end

  ...
end
```