# Passing params to iframe in rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a rails noob so I know I'm probably totally missing something here. I'm trying to pass a url to an iframe through my products controller.

This is my setup.

Products Controller

```
    def open_url
        @url = params[:url]
    end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "More Info", open_path(url: "http://www.ceratoboutique.com" + product.destination_url) %>
```

open_url.html.erb

```
<iframe src= "<%= @url %>" style="border: 0; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%" />
```

routes.rb

```
get '/open' => 'products#open_url', via: 'get'
```

I,ve checked out these two questions

[Rails 4 - Passing Params via link_to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706494/rails-4-passing-params-via-link-to)

[Opening a Link in a New Window within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352072/opening-a-link-in-a-new-window-within-an-iframe)

but i'm still lost, the url is passed to the browser but it does not seem to pass to the @url variable in my controller.

Debug Dump

> !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
>
> url: http://www.ceratoboutique.com/collections/tops/products/combo-blouse
>
> controller: products
>
> action: open_url

Comment: How have you checked whether @url is set?

Comment: I've added the debug dump for open_url page.

Comment: @url is set to nil although the url is passing through

Answer (score 0):

I decided to stick to rails conventions and make it a restful link. I still do not know why the original implementations did not work, but it worked using the show method in the controller.

Controller

```
def show
    @url = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "More Info", product_path(product) %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<iframe src= "<%= "http://www.ceratoboutique.com" + @product.destination_url %>" style="border: 0; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%" />
```

****Edit Added More Info for including I-Frame ****

I ran into a lot of problems trying to get my iframe to work in chrome and on Heroku so I combined the process if anyone needs it ever. I first deployed to Heroku with full SSL running on my site, then realized that iframe did not work in chrome for sites that were not running SSL. I redeployed configuring force SSL to false, but heroku still forced my app to SSL. I realized that config.force_ssl = true enables Strict Transport Security header(HSTS) with max-age of one year, so I had to expire HSTS using the following.

Expire SSL in application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :expire_hsts

  def expire_hsts
    response.headers["Strict-Transport-Security"] = 'max-age=0'
  end
```

In Production.rb

```
config.force_ssl = false
```

Then to make sure the x-frame showed in chrome browsers I added the following.

enable x-frame in chrome

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = { 'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL' }
```

You may want to run SSL on some of your pages, which can be done rather easily via the SSL enforcer gem linked below.

ssl-enforcer gem

https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer

Best of luck on navigating the ugliness that is the iFrame!